Display 2 different fonts within one word in HTML
I'm having a few problems trying to get both fonts working together in the one word and heading.
Would this be done with span I've tried to look into that but having no joy yet.
I am currently trying to achieve this:


You can surround each letter with a <span> element, apply a specific class to it, for each font, then surround the letters you would like to have the font applied to with the <span> elements.
For example, if you were to add this styling to a phrase like "Hello World", you can use this code below:
f1 class being the first font, and f2 being the second font.
HTML:
<span class="f1">H</span><span class="f2">e</span><span class="f1">l</span><span class="f2">l</span><span class="f1">o &ensp;</span><span class="f2">W</span><span class="f1">o</span><span class="f2">r</span><span class="f1">l</span><span class="f2">d</span>
CSS:
.f1 {font-family: [enter first font family here]} .f2 {font-family: [enter second font family here]}

thanks for replying, so in the css can i change that specific font family for the span?

Yes @MarkCallaghan I have edited my answer to show an example I have put together my self. It displays how you can use CSS and HTML to add a font to each individual character in a phrase.

@MarkCallaghan you can position the <span> elements however you would like your sentence to look. So, if you wanted "Hello" to have a different font from "World", you would just add a set of span tags around each word.
